# prime numbers property, Merten's theorem related sequence

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

Merten's third theorem states that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \log(p_n) \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_i}\right) = e^{-\gamma}$$ This is a particularly interesting product since $\log(p_n) \rightarrow \infty$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_i}\right) \rightarrow 0 $ hence Merten's theorem states a sort of balance between the two sequences ... Now obviously $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} p_n \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_i}\right) = \infty$$ but let $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and let $$ T_{\alpha}(p_n) =  p_n^{\alpha} \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha}}\right)$$ and observe that $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_{\alpha = 0} (p_n) = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_{\alpha = 1} (p_n) = \infty$. My question is: is there an $\alpha^* \in (0,1)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_{\alpha^* } (p_n) = k$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$? According to some of my numerical calculations, this is the case for $\alpha < 4/5$ and possibly above a little. The limit is $k = 0$ in these cases. But I am of course interested in a demonstration and if there is some $\alpha$ for which the limit is not zero but finite.

Comment: For $\alpha > 1$ : $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-n^{-\alpha})$ converges as well as $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-p_k^{-\alpha})=  \frac{1}{\zeta(\alpha)}$

Comment: Thank you, for the attention. Yes, that is true, but my interest is for $\alpha \in (0,1)$  ...

Comment: What do you not understand again ?

Comment: again ... :) please have patience with me, I have math as a hobby :) but let's get to the subject: as I said something seems wrong with that summation by parts I think the answer is  $-\frac{\pi(N+1)}{(N+1)^{\alpha}} + \sum_{p < N+1} p^{-\alpha}$

Comment: Then someone said that L(N) = \pi(N)(1 + o(1)) is false, and I do not know what to say ... how to prove this, I need a reference ... This is a question of mine specific for this subject : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295500/how-to-prove-a-known-prime-counting-function-asymptotic

Comment: Then lastly I do not understand why in that integration at the end you integrate form $1$ to $\alpha$ ... :D ? And there at the differentiation with respect to $\alpha$ my calculations output $-\frac{N^{1-\alpha}}{1 - \alpha}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since $-\log(1-x) = x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ for $\alpha > 1$, $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-n^{-\alpha})$ converges as well as $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-p_k^{-\alpha})=  \frac{1}{\zeta(\alpha)}$
- For $\alpha \in (1/2,1]$ : $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{-2\alpha}$ converges so that $$-\log \prod_{k=1}^K (1-p_k^{-\alpha}) =\underbrace{\mathcal{O}(1)+ \sum_{k=1}^K p_k^{-\alpha} \sim \sum_{n=2}^{p_K} \frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\log n}}_{\text{prime number theorem}} \sim \mathcal{O}(1)+C\frac{p_K^{1-\alpha}}{\log p_K}$$
  and by the PNT again $p_K \sim K \log K$
- For $\alpha > 0$  you can make the same reasoning $-\log \prod_{k=1}^K (1-p_k^{-\alpha}) \sim \sum_{k=1}^K p_k^{-\alpha} \sim \sum_{n=1}^{p_K} \frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\log n} \sim C\frac{p_K^{1-\alpha}}{\log K}$

Thus the answer is that $\lim_{K \to \infty} p_K^\alpha \prod_{k=1}^K (1-p_k^{-\alpha}) = 0$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C},\alpha \in (0,1)$ (or  $\Re(\alpha) \in (0,1)$) otherwise it diverges

---

In number theory $\sum_p$ means summing over the prime, $\sum_n$ means summing over the integers.  Let $\Re(\alpha)  \in (0,1)$ so that everything $\to \infty$,

$L(N) = \sum_{ n=2}^N \frac{1}{\ln n}$ and $\pi(N) = \sum_{p \le N} 1$.

By the PNT $L(N) \sim \pi(N)$ so that $ L(N) = \pi(N)(1+o(1))$. Summing by parts
$$\sum_{n =1}^N \pi(n) (n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha}) =\pi(N)(N^{-\alpha}-(N+1)^{-\alpha}) +\sum_{p < N} p^{-\alpha} $$
$$\sum_{n =1}^N L(n) (n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha}) =L(N)(N^{-\alpha}-(N+1)^{-\alpha}) +\sum_{n < N} \frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\ln n} $$

where $N^{-\alpha}-(N+1)^{-\alpha} = \int_N^{N+1} \alpha x^{-\alpha-1}dx \sim \alpha N^{-\alpha-1}$ so that $L(N)(N^{-\alpha}-(N+1)^{-\alpha})$ is much smaller than the sum

and
$$\sum_{n =1}^N \pi(n) (n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha})=\sum_{n =1}^N L(N)(1+o(1))   (n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha}) \\ \sim \sum_{n =1}^N L(N)(n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha})$$

Qed
$$\sum_{p < N} p^{-\alpha} \sim \sum_{2 \le n < N} \frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\ln n}$$

Finally $\frac{d}{d\alpha}\sum_{2 \le n < N}\frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\ln n}=-\sum_{2 \le n < N}n^{-\alpha} \sim \frac{N^{1-\alpha}-1}{1-\alpha}$ and
$$\sum_{p < N} p^{-\alpha} \sim \sum_{2 \le n < N}\frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\ln n} \sim \int_1^\alpha \frac{N^{1-a}-1}{a-1}da\sim \int_1^\alpha \frac{N^{1-a}-1}{\alpha-1}da = \frac{N^{1-\alpha}-2}{(1-\alpha)\ln N}\sim \frac{N^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)\ln N}$$
as claimed

Comment: I am not sure I understand there in that PNT sum ... $p_k \approx \frac{k}{\log(k)}$ hence you shouldn't have $\sum \left( \frac{n}{\log(n)} \right)^{-\alpha}$ ?  And is it ok to just replace terms like that? ... There are some differences ...

Comment: @CMarius You mean $\sum_{k=1}^K p_k^{-\alpha} \sim \sum_{n=2}^{p_K} \frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\log n}$. Look at $\sum_{n=2}^N \pi(n) (n^{-\alpha}-(n+1)^{-\alpha})$ use that $\pi(n) \sim \sum_{m=2}^n \frac{1}{\ln m}$ (the PNT) and summation by parts

Comment: $\sim$ is the symptotic comparison : $f(x) \sim g(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ iff $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$

Comment: Ok, but if that $C$ is positive isn't that meaning that $\log\prod(1 - p_k^{-\alpha}) \rightarrow -\infty$ hence $\prod(1 - p_k^{-\alpha}) \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: @CMarius Yes $\prod_p (1-p^{-\alpha}) \to 0$ for $\Re(\alpha) \in (0,1)$. I gave you the clues for using the PNT to compute the asymptotics of the involved terms. The logarithmic terms $\log f(n)$ are easier, you need a much sharper bound to transform it to a $\sim$ for $f(n)$ : If $\log f(n) = \log g(n)+o(1)$ then $f(n) \sim g(n)$

Comment: Thank you very very much :) I think I have more intuition than experience. Thus the answer is ... yes ... right? If so, please modify your answer

Comment: @CMarius Yes to what ? $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n^{\alpha} \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_i^{\alpha}}\right)$ always diverges as I shown its logarithm always diverges

Comment: $\log(\frac{1}{p_n^{\alpha} \prod(1 - p^{-\alpha})}) = -\log(p_n^{\alpha}) - \log(\prod(1 - p^{-\alpha})) \rightarrow +\infty$ hence $\log(p_n^{\alpha} \prod(1 - p^{-\alpha})) \rightarrow -\infty$  $\Rightarrow$ $p_n^{\alpha} \prod(1 - p^{-\alpha}) \rightarrow 0$ isn't it ?!

Comment: @CMarius Yes I see what you meant now (in the theory of $\zeta(s)$ we say a product diverges if it $\to 0$, because its logarithm diverges) I changed the conclusion.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for the ideas! Maybe I'll back with questions ...

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand the following symptotic comparisons: $\sum _{k=1}^K p_k^{-\alpha} \sim \sum_{n=2}^{p_K} \frac{n^{-\alpha}}{\log(n)}$ ... I wrote $\sum _{k=1}^K p_k^{-\alpha} = \sum_{k=2}^K \pi(p_k) (p_k^{-\alpha} - p_{k+1}^{-\alpha}) = sum by parts = -\pi(p_{K+1}) p_{K+1}^{-\alpha} + \pi(p_2) p_2^{-\alpha} - \sum_{k=2}^K p_{k+1}^{-\alpha} (\pi(p_{k}) - \pi(p_{k+1}))$                                 how to proceed ?

Comment: @CMarius I wrote the derivation in the answer

Comment: wow ... very beautiful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please excuse me for asking again something ... but if you can please have a look at one of my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291726/number-sequence-inequality Only if you sir have time ... thank you :)

Comment: Sir, I intend to write an article in which I use this information that you provided here. How should I acknowledge this? I posted another question, about something your answer uses here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295500/how-to-prove-a-known-prime-counting-function-asymptotic

Comment: I also think there is a little error in your summation by parts, but it does not seem to affect the reasoning